# Resizeable Custom NSPanel

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, hud

OK, here's my situation :

- I'm trying a HUD-like custom-controls collection, [SNRHUDKit](https://github.com/indragiek/SNRHUDKit).
- I'm specifically using `SNRHUDWindow` as my main window class
- No matter what, although it actually works, I can't get the `NSWindow` (or `NSPanel` - doesn't make much difference) to resize, when the user drags its lower-right corner.

The code for `SNRHUDWindow` is :

```
//
//  SNRHUDWindow.m
//  SNRHUDKit
//
//  Created by Indragie Karunaratne on 12-01-22.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 indragie.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import "SNRHUDWindow.h"
#import "NSBezierPath+MCAdditions.h"

#define SNRWindowTitlebarHeight         22.f
#define SNRWindowBorderColor            [NSColor blackColor]
#define SNRWindowTopColor               [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.240 alpha:0.960]
#define SNRWindowBottomColor            [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.150 alpha:0.960]
#define SNRWindowHighlightColor         [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1.000 alpha:0.200]
#define SNRWindowCornerRadius           5.f

#define SNRWindowTitleFont              [NSFont systemFontOfSize:11.f]
#define SNRWindowTitleColor             [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.700 alpha:1.000]
#define SNRWindowTitleShadowOffset      NSMakeSize(0.f, 1.f)
#define SNRWindowTitleShadowBlurRadius  1.f
#define SNRWindowTitleShadowColor       [NSColor blackColor]

#define SNRWindowButtonSize             NSMakeSize(18.f, 18.f)
#define SNRWindowButtonEdgeMargin       5.f
#define SNRWindowButtonBorderColor      [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.040 alpha:1.000]
#define SNRWindowButtonGradientBottomColor  [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.070 alpha:1.000]
#define SNRWindowButtonGradientTopColor     [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.220 alpha:1.000]
#define SNRWindowButtonDropShadowColor  [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1.000 alpha:0.100]
#define SNRWindowButtonCrossColor       [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.450 alpha:1.000]
#define SNRWindowButtonCrossInset       1.f
#define SNRWindowButtonHighlightOverlayColor [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:0.000 alpha:0.300]
#define SNRWindowButtonInnerShadowColor [NSColor colorWithDeviceWhite:1.000 alpha:0.100]
#define SNRWindowButtonInnerShadowOffset NSMakeSize(0.f, 0.f)
#define SNRWindowButtonInnerShadowBlurRadius    1.f

@interface SNRHUDWindowButtonCell : NSButtonCell
@end

@interface SNRHUDWindowFrameView : NSView
- (void)snr_drawTitleInRect:(NSRect)rect;
@end

@implementation SNRHUDWindow {
    NSView *__customContentView;
}

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation
{
    if ((self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:bufferingType defer:deferCreation])) {
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
        [self setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
        [self setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSRect)contentRectForFrameRect:(NSRect)windowFrame
{
    windowFrame.origin = NSZeroPoint;
    windowFrame.size.height -= SNRWindowTitlebarHeight;
    return windowFrame;
}

+ (NSRect)frameRectForContentRect:(NSRect)windowContentRect
                        styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle
{
    windowContentRect.size.height += SNRWindowTitlebarHeight;
    return windowContentRect;
}

- (NSRect)frameRectForContentRect:(NSRect)windowContent
{
    windowContent.size.height += SNRWindowTitlebarHeight;
    return windowContent;
}

- (void)setContentView:(NSView *)aView
{
    if ([__customContentView isEqualTo:aView]) {
        return;
    }
    NSRect bounds = [self frame];
    bounds.origin = NSZeroPoint;
    SNRHUDWindowFrameView *frameView = [super contentView];
    if (!frameView) {
        frameView = [[SNRHUDWindowFrameView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
        NSSize buttonSize = SNRWindowButtonSize;
        NSRect buttonRect = NSMakeRect(SNRWindowButtonEdgeMargin, NSMaxY(frameView.bounds) -(SNRWindowButtonEdgeMargin + buttonSize.height), buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);
        NSButton *closeButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonRect];
        [closeButton setCell:[[SNRHUDWindowButtonCell alloc] init]];
        [closeButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryChangeButton];
        [closeButton setTarget:self];
        [closeButton setAction:@selector(close)];
        [closeButton setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin];
        [frameView addSubview:closeButton];
        [super setContentView:frameView];
    }
    if (__customContentView) {
        [__customContentView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    __customContentView = aView;
    [__customContentView setFrame:[self contentRectForFrameRect:bounds]];
    [__customContentView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
    [frameView addSubview:__customContentView];
}

- (NSView *)contentView
{
    return __customContentView;
}

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)aString
{
    [super setTitle:aString];
    [[super contentView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
@end

@implementation SNRHUDWindowFrameView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect drawingRect = NSInsetRect(self.bounds, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:drawingRect xRadius:SNRWindowCornerRadius yRadius:SNRWindowCornerRadius];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [path addClip];
    // Fill in the title bar with a gradient background
    NSRect titleBarRect = NSMakeRect(0.f, NSMaxY(self.bounds) - SNRWindowTitlebarHeight, self.bounds.size.width, SNRWindowTitlebarHeight);
    NSGradient *titlebarGradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:SNRWindowBottomColor endingColor:SNRWindowTopColor];
    [titlebarGradient drawInRect:titleBarRect angle:90.f];
    // Draw the window title
    [self snr_drawTitleInRect:titleBarRect];
    // Rest of the window has a solid fill
    NSRect bottomRect = NSMakeRect(0.f, 0.f, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - SNRWindowTitlebarHeight);
    [SNRWindowBottomColor set];
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:bottomRect];
    // Draw the highlight line around the top edge of the window
    // Outset the width of the rectangle by 0.5px so that the highlight "bleeds" around the rounded corners
    // Outset the height by 1px so that the line is drawn right below the border
    NSRect highlightRect = NSInsetRect(drawingRect, 0.f, 0.5f);
    // Make the height of the highlight rect something bigger than the bounds so that it won't show up on the bottom
    highlightRect.size.height += 50.f;
    highlightRect.origin.y -= 50.f;
    NSBezierPath *highlightPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:highlightRect xRadius:SNRWindowCornerRadius yRadius:SNRWindowCornerRadius];
    [SNRWindowHighlightColor set];
    [highlightPath stroke];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
    [SNRWindowBorderColor set];
    [path stroke];
}

- (void)snr_drawTitleInRect:(NSRect)titleBarRect
{
    NSString *title = [[self window] title];
    if (!title) { return; }
    NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
    [shadow setShadowColor:SNRWindowTitleShadowColor];
    [shadow setShadowOffset:SNRWindowTitleShadowOffset];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius:SNRWindowTitleShadowBlurRadius];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    [style setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:SNRWindowTitleColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, SNRWindowTitleFont, NSFontAttributeName, shadow, NSShadowAttributeName, style, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
    NSAttributedString *attrTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attributes];
    NSSize titleSize = attrTitle.size;
    NSRect titleRect = NSMakeRect(0.f, NSMidY(titleBarRect) - (titleSize.height / 2.f), titleBarRect.size.width, titleSize.height);
    [attrTitle drawInRect:NSIntegralRect(titleRect)];
}
@end

@implementation SNRHUDWindowButtonCell

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSRect drawingRect = NSInsetRect(cellFrame, 1.5f, 1.5f);
    drawingRect.origin.y = 0.5f;
    NSRect dropShadowRect = drawingRect;
    dropShadowRect.origin.y += 1.f;
    // Draw the drop shadow so that the bottom edge peeks through
    NSBezierPath *dropShadow = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:dropShadowRect];
    [SNRWindowButtonDropShadowColor set];
    [dropShadow stroke];
    // Draw the main circle w/ gradient & border on top of it
    NSBezierPath *circle = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:drawingRect];
    NSGradient *gradient = [[NSGradient alloc] initWithStartingColor:SNRWindowButtonGradientBottomColor endingColor:SNRWindowButtonGradientTopColor];
    [gradient drawInBezierPath:circle angle:270.f];
    [SNRWindowButtonBorderColor set];
    [circle stroke];
    // Draw the cross
    NSBezierPath *cross = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGFloat boxDimension = floor(drawingRect.size.width * cos(45.f)) - SNRWindowButtonCrossInset;
    CGFloat origin = round((drawingRect.size.width - boxDimension) / 2.f);
    NSRect boxRect = NSMakeRect(1.f + origin, origin, boxDimension, boxDimension);
    NSPoint bottomLeft = NSMakePoint(boxRect.origin.x, NSMaxY(boxRect));
    NSPoint topRight = NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(boxRect), boxRect.origin.y);
    NSPoint bottomRight = NSMakePoint(topRight.x, bottomLeft.y);
    NSPoint topLeft = NSMakePoint(bottomLeft.x, topRight.y);
    [cross moveToPoint:bottomLeft];
    [cross lineToPoint:topRight];
    [cross moveToPoint:bottomRight];
    [cross lineToPoint:topLeft];
    [SNRWindowButtonCrossColor set];
    [cross setLineWidth:2.f];
    [cross stroke];
    // Draw the inner shadow
    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadow setShadowColor:SNRWindowButtonInnerShadowColor];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius:SNRWindowButtonInnerShadowBlurRadius];
    [shadow setShadowOffset:SNRWindowButtonInnerShadowOffset];
    NSRect shadowRect = drawingRect;
    shadowRect.size.height = origin;
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSBezierPath clipRect:shadowRect];
    [circle fillWithInnerShadow:shadow];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
    if ([self isHighlighted]) {
        [SNRWindowButtonHighlightOverlayColor set];
        [circle fill];
    }
}

@end
```

Any ideas what could be responsible for the `NSPanel` losing its resizing ability?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this framework as well, and the reason that resizing doesn't work by default is this line in the initWithContentRect method:

```
if ((self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:bufferingType defer:deferCreation])) {
```

As you can see, instead of passing the windowStyle bitmask provided to super's init method, it passes through just NSBorderlessWindowMask. A bit of sniffing around shows that for resizing to be possible at all, the styleMask must have NSResizableWindowMask included in the bitmask.

So, changing the line to

```
if ((self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask backing:bufferingType defer:deferCreation])) {
```

should solve your problem.